# Refresh buffer while in Tmux copy mode?

Tags: tmux

While in copy mode (<kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd>) is there a way to refresh the buffer without having to leave copy mode?

This would be helpful while scrolling through long running output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `refresh-from-pane` <sup>(requires tmux 3.2+)</sup> command in copy mode. The default key binding for it is `r`.

---

To check if you `tmux` supports `refresh-from-pane`:

```
$ tmux list-keys -T copy-mode | grep refresh-from-pane
bind-key -T copy-mode r  send-keys -X refresh-from-pane
$ tmux list-keys -T copy-mode-vi | grep refresh-from-pane
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi r  send-keys -X refresh-from-pane
```

Comment: While in copy mode, if I type prefix-r nothing happens, although I do see the command listed in the manpage docs (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html).
I tried to create a binding in my .tmux.conf: `bind-key -T copy-mode g refresh-from-pane` but it errors out with "unknown command". Do you know how I could use `refresh-from-pane`?

Comment: just `r`, no prefix.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work for me. See anything fishy in my .tmux config? https://github.com/jonbri/dotfiles/blob/master/.files/.tmux.conf

Comment: updated by adding how to check if your tmux supports `refresh-from-pane`.

Comment: `tmux -V`: `tmux 3.0a`